# How to split enum variants and their contents in Rust to generate correct JSON schema

Tags: json, rust, serde

With [schemars](https://docs.rs/schemars/0.7.6/schemars/), it is possible to generate a JSON schema from Rust code.

Consider this JSON example:

```
{
   "cause" : {
      "type" : "EVT1",
      "payload" : {
         "cause_id" : "ABC-123"
      }
   } 
}
```

and the Rust code used to generate the schema:

```
use schemar::JsonSchema;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize, JsonSchema)]
struct Cause {
    _type: EventType,
    payload: EventPayload,
}

#[derive(Serialize, JsonSchema)]
enum EventType {
    EVT1 { param1: String, param2: String },
    EVT2 { param1: String },
}

#[derive(Serialize, JsonSchema)]
enum EventPayload {
    // ?
}
```

`EventType` contains the type of event in the name of the variant, and the payload is specified by `EventType` as well. `EventPayload` is superfluous.

Is there any possibility to configure serde so that the name of the `EventType` variant will be used as `type`, the contents of it as `payload`? The `payload` depends on `EventType`.

What do I expect?

- `_type` shall be restricted to the variants of `EventType`
- the `payload` of `cause` is directly dependant of `_type`
- Ideally, the schema generation would use the name of `EventType` variant as `_type`, and take the `payload` from the variants contents.

Comment: From your question it is unclear to me as to what it produces vs what you were expecting. Perhaps you could elaborate and clarify? https://serde.rs/json.html

Comment: the json above is to be expected. I also update the questions. it boils down to use EventType enum to set `_type` and `payload`

Comment: I am in process of learning Rust myself. I looked at this section of the Github repo: https://github.com/serde-rs/json#getting-help .. Not sure if anything in here helps? https://users.rust-lang.org/t/deserializing-enum-json-field-with-serde-with-multiple-types/5424/2

Comment: hmm could be an option to have a customer serializer function doing the job. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @nomad serde directly supports mapping enums: https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html here it looks to me like you want "internal tagging", but you may need to further annotate your structures and enums. You'll need to check if schemars supports internally tagged enums but it would seem insane that it would not.

Comment: yes, I'm also reading through serdes documentation, but again, `EventType` combines both. Maybe there is a need to split it up even further. Currently trying a few things.

Comment: The duplicates [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=858bbb72ef5533e62bcece9fa2643891). Specifically, you want the [*adjacently tagged*](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#adjacently-tagged) representation.

Comment: ahh nice! @shepmaster thank you for providing an example. Will do so in the future as well. I had a struct in between that has generated some confusion.